# How can I achieve a "hand-drawn" look?

Tags: rendering, texture-painting

So I watched "Suits" Episode of the Netflix Series "Love, Death & Robots".

I really liked the overall style. Sometimes you see it's low fps so I guess it's almost completely hand-drawn. Anyway, I took these screenshots:

[image]
[image]

I started Blender, created a feather mesh and used the hair-particle system to achieve this:

[image]

This is a hand-drawn texture on a default material (blender internal, viewport) with emission 0.5 (left) / shadeless (right).
But I am not yet pleased with the look. Do you have any tips to achieve this fluffy look?

Comment: maybe you can use the same technique I use there at 7:50 in this video? "Above and under the ocean-Blender 2.8" on YT https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i43GXeo5vmg here a jpg of this moment on my vid
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyHbC.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyHbC.jpg)
the both colors are distributed by the A.O 1-enable A.O in render settings
2-in shader editor add a principled BSDF
3-in a color Mix RGB you put your first color and a second one for the "shadow parts"
4-then you put a A.O node in the Fac. no setting required in this node. just use AO output

Answer (score 3):

You need to create 2 or 3 variation meshes to correctly display what you want. You can use 1 emitter but different particle settings (many particle systems inside 1 emitter). Since you´re using hair, the scruffy look is given by the parameters in Kink, Twist and Roughness (use custom roughness curve). Hope this helps. Yes, it will look fantastic, but please create 2 or 3 variations to be used with the 2 or 3 particle systems for the body emitter (one of the systems irremediably will be long feather looking hairs scruffed).

Hope this helps.
BFCT_Schiller

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While this is good advice, I'm still hoping to get some tips about shading. Like if I should use Transparency, Toon shading, Ambient Occlusion or Subsurface Scattering. Also not sure about alpha blending (there are different techniques for bushes with a lot of leafs - which is similar to my self-intersecting feathers.)

Comment: Hi. I just noted this has a 50 point bounty. At the moment my machine is rendering, but I´m definietly interested in giving you a walkthrough with pictures. You already have achieved a good start on the toony look. Remember after all there´s a lot of compositing going on with those references you showed. Don´t use SSS, fake it on the paint. Ambient occlussion: yes, use it with MASKS, you need to ID your materials with cryptomatte or Object ID so you can tweak the AO colors once it´s rendered.

Comment: I'd be happy to give you the bounty, I'd even increase it if I really like it :)

Comment: That sounds good. I´ll get right to it in some more hours. I still have to deliver some deadlines due today.

Comment: I´ll be uploading in a few moments the video explaining the appearance of the feathers. I don´t know if the bounty is editable. (I don´t think so).

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 approaches to stylize this as the reference:
Route 1: In viewport
Route 2: In compositing.

With that as a -starting point- I´m going to be emphasizing that it's important that the modeling of the feathers look very stylized as well. I recently finished compositing a short NPR 360 video so all of this is sorted already. Your question (now that I've read it again and again) wants to go the "compositing" route. Which is how you want to merge your passes. In that context: Use Albedo (flat colors, no shadow cast) as your main base layer to compose. Then Use the AO in 23% multiply with tinting on it (in your reference the chickens are tinted by the ambient color to purple). You need to render shadows in another pass. Tint them. You don´t need to use SSS, but if you want (takes too much time) also compose it as add. I tend to create a Blender shader with a specific Rimlight angle degree. Create a pass with it, override the scene, and then I have pure white and black colors, like in this example: https://youtu.be/DM-HikLSa6g
That way, in compositing, I can tint the light. Light also needs to be stylized in the reference you sent.

Finally, I´m addressing the importance of modeling as stylized as your reference using a particle HAIR system. And the parameters I initially referred to you in the first post of this thread, you can find them at minute 17 onward which are: Clump, Roughness and interpolation.
In closing: It´s important you do flat shades. Get them out of your renders ready to be worked on the compositor. Also, make sure your bounces are at 1. You don´t need to spread light everywhere. You most likely need flat stuff everywhere. Override your render layers. Jump to minute 17 to see the clump and roughness parameters on hair setup. I know these tips could help you on your setup: https://youtu.be/IZH1NY0TJ6k

Let me know if this works for you.
BFCT_Schiller.

Comment: will watch it later, thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have additional information, please use the edit link below your original answer and add the information there. Stack Exchange is not a forum, please learn the rules.

Comment: Bounty is about to end. I will give it to you, even though I'm not 100% satisfied. But I opened the bounty to get more attention to the question, and you answered quite extensive, so I will honor your effort. I think I can learn at least a few tricks from your video. Thanks

Comment: Ok. What wasn't adressed? The compositing part?

Answer (score -1):

here is a youtube link that should hopefully answer your question:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOMjQbVvnXU

[image]

[image]

Comment: Link only answers are not what this site tries to do. If the link diaappears or changes then the answer will not work any more.
Please outline the workflow and principal ideas. So that the answer stands on its own

Comment: This is a very broad answer, and I have to admit I don't see the relevance to my question at all. This is all flat geometry and it shows how to render pixelated - I was talking about fluffy feathers in a handdrawn look.